# I found a typo in the Portuguese translation of Bitcoin Core

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core-development

I'm using the Bitcoin Core wallet version 22.0.0 and there is an error, a typo, in the Portuguese.

Will this translation be corrected in the next version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can correct the typo on Transifex, which is the platform used by Bitcoin Core to translate into all supported languages.

https://www.transifex.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/